# Is ISBN/ISSN + Epubcfi good enough to link to Epub paragraph from outside world?

Tags: uniqueidentifier, epub

To link to mybook.epub,

http://idpf.org/epub/linking/cfi/epub-cfi.html#gloss-cfi-pub suggests:

```
book.epub#epubcfi(/6/4[chap01ref]!/4[body01]/10[para05]/3:10)
```

thinking of using isbn/issn for books instead, eg.

```
isbn-12#epubcfi(/6/4[chap01ref]!/4[body01]/10[para05]/3:10)
```

Is there a better, standard way of linking ? 
cannot see one in epub specs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't a standard way of linking.

Moreover, your ISBN idea has several issues :

1. different editions of the same book (different author, digital vs paper version, pocket vs fullsize, reeditions, grouping of several books of a same trilogy into a single book, etc...) will have different ISBN.
2. some amazon kindle-published books won't even have ISBN, only ASIN.
3. books before 2007 will have a 10-digit ISBN, from 2007 and newer 13-digit ISBN, so reedition of old books might have isbn in the new format.
4. non-officially published books (self-published, ie available on the net, self-printed, etc...) won't have ISBN either. magazines will have ISSN. paper research will have DOI, which is complex.

Comment: hmm thanks for the info, haven't thought at all about #2 and #4